# Output of string in function gives an object

Tags: javascript

I tring to print to string but it's for some reason gives an object..

I want to get (example 20220515) as string and then slice it, to get two first digits.

```
// Button
const birthDate = document.querySelector('#dateSubmit');

// Date input
birthDate.onclick = function() {
    let in1 = document.querySelector('#birthday');
    let birthDate = (in1.value).replaceAll("-", "");
    let dateNow = 20220515;
    let old = dateNow - parseInt(birthDate); // 320411
    let result = toString(old);

    console.log(result);  // [object Undefined] ?

    console.log(typeof result);  // string 
}
```

Comment: what result do you expect?

Comment: Hi! What do the elements that code is using look like? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: I want to get (example 20220515) as string and then slice it, to get two first digits.

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a typo, you want `old.toString()`, not `toString(old)` (and you can't use those date-like numbers like that, more below¹). But then the question is: What is this global `toString` function and why, when you call it, do you get the string `"[object Undefined]"`?? Example:

```js
console.log(toString());      // "[object Undefined]"
console.log(toString(42));    // "[object Undefined]"
console.log(toString("hi"));  // "[object Undefined]"
```

The answer lies in the complex nature of the JavaScript global environment. The global environment closes over the global object (see the spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-newglobalenvironment) and [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/executable-code-and-execution-contexts.html#sec-setrealmglobalobject)). That means that all properties of the global object are accessible as globals. The global object inherits from `Object.prototype`, which defines `toString`, so the global `toString` is `Object.prototype.toString`:

```js
console.log(toString === Object.prototype.toString); // true
```

Okay, so far so good. But why does calling `toString` give us `"[object Undefined]"`?

Because `Object.prototype.toString` is defined as a strict mode function, which means freestanding calls to it like `toString()` get the value `undefined` as `this`. `Object.prototype.toString` [is defined](https://%5D%5B1%5D) as returning `"[object Undefined]"` when you call it with `this` set to `undefined`.

---

¹ So about those date-like numbers, `20220515` and such. You can't usefully do date math with those numbers. Instead, use `Date` instances and milliseconds-since-The-Epoch, the number value (the number of milliseconds since Jan 1st 1970 at midnight GMT) that underlies dates. (Or you might look at using the upcoming [`Temporal`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal) stuff.) For example:

```
const dateNow = new Date();
const birthDate = new Date(in1.value); // **ONLY** if it's in the right format
const millisecondsSinceBirth = birthDate - birthday;
```

From those milliseconds you can work out years, months, days, etc.

`new Date` only knows how to parse a very specific format, see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791623/date-parse-in-javascript/4791655#4791655) for parsing suggestions for other formats.

Comment: all properties of the global object are accessible as globals. The global object inherits from Object.prototype, which defines toString, so the global toString is Object.prototype.toString:

Comment: @Pavel - That looks like a quote of part of the answer. Did you mean to ask something about it?

Comment: I wanted to get a string and then manipulate it.
It turns out that the toString() method converts the data into an object?

Comment: @Pavel - No, what you're getting is a **string**, not an object; the string just has the word "object" in it. It's the same string you'd get by writing `let result = "[object Undefined]";` You want `old.toString()` instead, which calls `toString` with `old` as `this`, so it converts the number in `old` to a string representation of that number.

Comment: Now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

The function toString() does not pass a variable to it, its general formula:

Number.prototype.toString()

it is like this to convert the number to text,

modify the code as follows:

```
// Button
const birthDate = document.querySelector('#dateSubmit');

// Date input
birthDate.onclick = function() {
let in1 = document.querySelector('#birthday');
let birthDate = (in1.value).replaceAll("-", "");
let dateNow = 20220515;
let old = dateNow - parseInt(birthDate); // 320411
let result = old.toString();

console.log(result);  // 320411

console.log(typeof result);  // string 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I should have used **"String()"**  instead  **"toString()"**

```
// Button
const birthDate = document.querySelector('#dateSubmit');

// Date input
birthDate.onclick = function() {
    let in1 = document.querySelector('#birthday');
    let birthDate = (in1.value).replaceAll("-", "");
    let dateNow = 20220515;
    const num = dateNow - parseInt(birthDate); // 320411

    const first2Str = String(num).slice(0, 2); // ️ '13'
    const first2Num = Number(first2Str); // ️ 13

    console.log(first2Num);

}
```