# How to sort by oldest and newest using date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a presentation like this, of course, with more books, I want to sort the books based on the oldest and newest, how should I do this?

```
const userBooks = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "",
    author: "",
    genre: "",
    date: "2022-1-12",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "",
    author: "",
    genre: "",
    date: "2022-2-8",
  },
];
```

Comment: Please do research before posting here. Sorting an array by a field is trivial and how to do it can be found easily. The main issue is probably your date's string format, not sure if that will parse as-is.

Comment: What should be the date format?

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10123953/how-to-sort-an-object-array-by-date-property?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C694.4854) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791623/date-parse-in-javascript/4791655#4791655). (I should have voted duplicate rather than needs focus, my bad.)

Comment: How do I put this format?

Comment: @EhsanKey_ - Again, please see [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791623/date-parse-in-javascript/4791655#4791655) and ignore answers that assume `new Date` will work with your date strings. It won't, reliably, cross-browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this to sort it by date descending:

```
let descending = userBooks.sort((x,y) => new Date(y.date) - new Date(x.date))
```

or by date ascending:

```
let ascending = userBooks.sort((x,y) => new Date(x.date) - new Date(y.date))
```

Answer (score -1):

firstly save the date using javascript date function and
consider this page
https://stackabuse.com/how-to-sort-an-array-by-date-in-javascript/

Answer (score -1):

if you use new Data(userBooks.data) for comparing array's elements you're good to go.
I used .sort method:

```
let sortedUserBooks = userBooks.sort((a, b) => {
  return new Date(a.date) - new Date(b.date)
})

console.log(sortedUserBooks)
```

**and here is result:**

```
[
  { id: 3, name: '', author: '', genre: '', date: '2022-1-5' },
  { id: 1, name: '', author: '', genre: '', date: '2022-1-12' },
  { id: 2, name: '', author: '', genre: '', date: '2022-2-8' }
]
```

I added third object to check if it works.